# SSJS interpretation seems to be different from regular Javascript

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I found a difference between Lotus Domino SSJS iterpretation and regular Javascript.

Look at this snippet...

```
var mister = "mister in the hat".replace(" ", "-");
return mister
```

Regular Javascript does replave only once. The result is "mister-in the hat".
SSJS does full replace. The result is "mister-in-the-hat".

Is there any documentation, in what way the SSJS is diferent from regular JS?

Comment: @JiKra: Try to use *var mister = "mister in the hat".replaceFirst(" ", "-");* instead.

Comment: @freakish - I think you should do research before making a uninformed statement like that. It doesn't help the OP - and using Node.js as a reference is about as helpful as saying "I tried it in Logo and it works great, dunno what your problem is"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect Server-Side JavaScript will be influenced more by Java rather than JavaScript. This is because any SSJS written is just passed as a string to a Java method that parses the code at runtime. I know of ither differences to CSJS - parseInt, for example, defaults to base 10, not base 8 (JavaScript default).

The behaviour is documented in the Domino Designer help, under Lotus Domino Designer XPages Reference - Standard (JavaScript) - String - Replace. If in doubt, check out the Help. It's very good for these libraries, with plenty of examples as well as documentation.

Comment: I have checked the help for String replace, and the given example is not correct (8.5.3). *var cities = new String("Paris   Moscow   Tokyo");
cities.replace("   ", "---")* returns *Paris---Moscow---Tokyo*

Comment: OK, thx for your answer. Help is good, but I'd rather have some kind of reference book with those differences fully explained to avoid another surprises in the future. You know - what and why...

Comment: @JiKra: I would second with Paul. The following command `"mister in the hat".getClass().getName();` would return you `java.lang.String`, a clear indication that Java class is being used. Using this class name you can go to Java documentation to look for the its associated methods and properties. Also this is the replace method, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence), that is being called. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: What do you mean by `any SSJS written is just passed as a string to a Java method that parses the code at runtime`? Node.js is written in C++ and JavaScript (V8), isn't it? Or are you refering to Lotus Domino only?

Comment: @Naveen Ok, I get it. I sense Javascript, even server-side, differently then Java. Maybe it was not the best shot for IBM developers to call it javascript, but it doesn't matter. From now, I will use Domino SSJS more like java then javascript. Anyway, thx for your comment, too. :-)

Comment: @JiKra >Maybe it was not the best shot for IBM developers to call it javascript - but they call it SSJS ;-)

Comment: @freakish - Note the tags "xpages" and "lotus-domino" on the post, then please refer to http://xpages.info - however i do admit the "javascript" tag on the post is a mis-tag, and I have re-tagged the post to remove javascript for future clarity.

Comment: Has anybody tested it in Rhino? What does it do there?

Comment: I tested "mister in the hat".replace(" ", "-"); in Rhino. Returns "mister-in the hat" as it should be in JS